# Is it possible to open integrated terminals from VS Code in a separate window?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

In VS Code, is it possible to open the terminals in a separate window?
So far my research has pointed to a resounding no, but I'm curious if anyone has a solution or workaround.

Comment: related question: [Visual Studio Code open tab in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43362133/11107541)

Answer (score 43):

In Insiders v1.86 out tomorrow, you can move a terminal to a new (floating) window with the new command:

```
// Move Terminal into New Window
workbench.action.terminal.moveIntoNewWindow
```

For more on these floating windows, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233318/836330

---

As of **Insiders** v1.84 you can also open an editor in a separate window.  Run this command:

```
View: Move Active Editor into a New Window
```

So if you have terminal in an editor then that editor (i.e., containing a terminal) can be moved to a new separate window.  I believe the ultimate goal is to be able to move a terminal in the Panel, etc. to a new window but that doesn't work yet.

Consider this keybinding which moves the current terminal instance to an editor and then to a new window (there is no obvious visual movement to the editor first).

```json
{
  "key": "shift+alt+z",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    // "interval": 200,   // not necessary
    "sequence": [
      "terminal.focus",
      "workbench.action.terminal.moveToEditor",
      "workbench.action.experimentalMoveEditorIntoNewWindowAction",
    ]
  },
}
```

Demo:

[image: move terminal editor to new window]

Note that the new window terminal is linked to the old window, as in the demo I print out an editor filename from the old window in the new window terminal

---

> #### Move terminals between windows
>
> It's now possible to move terminals between windows by detaching via
> `Terminal: Detach Session` in one and attaching to another with
> `Terminal: Attach to Session`. In the future this should help enable
> cross-window drag and drop!

Lots of changes in v1.58: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_58.md#terminals-in-the-editor-area

For v1.59 moving the terminal changes - including dragging and dropping onto another window, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_59.md#drag-and-drop-terminals-across-windows

> Drag and drop terminals across windows

> Drag terminals from the tabs
> list or editor area of one window into the tabs list, editor area, or
> panel of another window.

[image]

### Terminals in the editor area

Terminals can now be created in or moved to the editor area, enabling a multi-dimensional grid layout that persists and remains visible regardless of panel state.

To use terminals in the editor area, there are several options:

Create via the Create Terminal in Editor Area command.
Move a terminal from the panel to the editor by dragging and dropping from the tabs list.
Running Move Terminal into Editor Area with a terminal focused.
Moving into the editor area via the terminal tab context menu action.

[image: terminals in editors demo]

The new `terminal.integrated.defaultLocation` setting can be set to editor to direct newly created terminals to the editor area by default.

Comment: I am using Python and when I press F5 to debug it always opens a terminal in the **same window** as my source code.  I don't like that. I want F5 to open the terminal in a different window.  I guess the best solution is to open the same project and python environment in a different window, and then if I want to debug, I have to Ctrl-K+S in one window, click the other window, and then hit F5. Not very convenient though.

Comment: Just a note: if you work with remote connections only a window that is connected to the same remote can detach/attach or drag'n'drop (which is in effect just detach, attach + position)

Comment: The dumb workaround: as of now (1.85.1) if you only have ONE shell open, you need to click into the Terminal tab in VSCode and then click the name of the shell session (typically on the right) and either click and drag it into the editor area OR click and choose "Move Terminal into Editor Area" in the menu that pops up and THEN you can drag out the tab to a new window (or another window). This seems to preserve the working directory as well. If you open a second shell session with the + you can drag either of them directly out to a new window directly which seems like horrible UX.

Comment: See also Mark's excellent demo elsewhere, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233318/3794873

Answer (score 20):

Please Try:

1. `File > Open New Window`
2. <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> > `Terminal: Create New Terminal in Editor Area`

You can add keybinding to the commands at your convenience.

Comment: It gives me following error: The active editor must contain an openable resource.

Comment: @MiBe thanks for the feedback. I have edited the answer. Please let me know if you find any more issues.

Comment: After doing this, you can then use `ctrl+k o` to move the terminal into a separate window entirely

Answer (score 16):

i think that the OP wants to create a separate window for the terminal but still have the separated terminal linked to the code editor in the original window (that's what i want too). so that when you run the code in the editor the output is shown in the terminal in the separate window. but if you simply open up a new window of vscode and either open a terminal there or drag and drop the terminal from the original window into the new window, the new terminal is not the same session of the terminal. it is a separate independent unconnected terminal. running the code in the editor does not show output in the new separate terminal. all you have achieved is creating a new unconnected terminal. which you could have just accomplished by opening up a regular terminal window i.e. the one from windows os main menu, no need even to use vscode.

Answer (score 8):

> This answer is now outdated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273093) for instructions on moving terminal panes between VS Code windows. This answer still works but is no longer a necessary workaround.

You can't detach the panes in VSCode, which IMO is a bit of a pain since Visual Studio can detach panes all day long.

There is a workaround though, you can open a new window in VSCode and maximize the terminal pane in that window.

[image: Maximized Terminal Pane]

Comment: What is the point of that?Why not just open a terminal window and maximize that? cmd? powershell? or sth?

Comment: In my case I want to match the theme of the editor + terminal

Comment: @Sohrab There might be some extensions that will open a terminal in VSCode, like Stripe.

Answer (score 6):

One reason you'd want to do this is to have the Python terminal on a second monitor while still being able to use Python interactively (`shift`+`enter` way). Attaching/detaching didn't work for me, nor can you open separate terminals.

What you can do is simply resize your one window across the screen borders! Then right click on the terminal tab/header and click `Move panel to the left` and voila!

[image: Two screen setup]

Comment: This "Move Panel to Left" is excellent for wide-screen monitors. Thank you. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Superb suggestion for wide-screen monitors.

Answer (score 6):

#### VS Code 1.86+ answer

You can use the "Move Terminal into New Window" context menu action in the terminal tab's context menu, or the `Terminal: Move Terminal into New Window` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) (you can create a keyboard shortcut for it using its command ID, `workbench.action.terminal.moveIntoNewWindow`). The related PR which added this is [Add move terminal into new window action/menu item #201325](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/201325)

#### VS Code 1.85 answer

Terminals could already be dragged into the editor area, but [now that auxiliary windows / floating editor windows are a thing](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_floating-editor-windows), you can drag them into the editor area of an auxiliary window (auxiliary windows don't support panels yet).

You can write a keyboard shortcut to create a new terminal in the editor area, and then move that editor to a new detached window, and not create a new one when an existing one is already focused but just move the focused one, put this in your keybindings.json, which you can open by running `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette):

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.createTerminalEditor",
            "workbench.action.moveEditorToNewWindow",
        ],
    },
    "when": "!isAuxiliaryWindowFocusedContext && !terminalFocus && !terminalEditorFocus", // !terminalIsOpen
},
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "workbench.action.moveEditorToNewWindow",
    "when": "!isAuxiliaryWindowFocusedContext && terminalEditorFocus"
},
```

I also tried to handle the case when an existing terminal is focused in the Terminal Panel, but it didn't work (maybe due to timing-related issues), but here it is in case you're interested:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "workbench.action.terminal.moveToEditor",
            "workbench.action.moveEditorToNewWindow",
        ],
    },
    "when": "!isAuxiliaryWindowFocusedContext && terminalFocus"
},
```

Note that `workbench.action.moveEditorToNewWindow` was previously called `workbench.action.moveEditorToNewDetachedWindow` (I think while it was still in VS Code Insiders and not yet released to Stable).

#### VS Code Pre-1.85 answer

The ideal case of what you're asking for is tracked by two issue tickets that are still open (not implemented):

- [Extract the integrated terminal #34442](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34442)
- [Allow for floating windows
  #10121](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121) (a more general request covering all Panels)

You can give those issue tickets a thumbs up reaction to show support for them getting implemented, and subscribe to them to get notified about discussions and updates. <sup><sub>[But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

As for workarounds, you can create a new and empty VS Code window (with no workspace folder), and drag the terminal from your pre-existing window into that one. You can also detach the session from one VS Code window, and then reattach it into another one (using the `Terminal: Detach Session` and `Terminal: Attach to Session` commands in the command palette respectively). See also the [user docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/advanced#_moving-terminals-between-windows).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new window by going to File → New Window.
2. Open up a new terminal inside of it.
3. Go to your folder (`cd your\projectfolder\path`).

And here you are, you have a terminal for your project inside it's own seperate window.

Answer (score 2):

Try Сtrl+Shift+c.
For me, it opens the folder the script is within in a command prompt window.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the terminal to be side-by-side instead of below the editor.  And then make your window very wide.  It is *almost* as good as having two windows.

1. Right click on the TERMINAL tab.
2. Select "Move Views to Side Panel"
3. Make your window very wide

[image]

Comment: This is easily the best workaround that I've found! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to split a terminal window with VS Code. Because I also searched the way a lot. Maybe you imagine like below.
[image]

Instead, I recommend using the 'Tab' style. That means using the terminal as one of the editing tabs like Python file. It's very convenient for me.
[image]

You can also find the button like below.
[image]

Then, you can bind the menu with a shortcut. I prefer to set Ctrl+KM.
[image]

In the shortcut menu, search "move terminal into editor area"
[image]

End!

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the file keybindings.json, and add this script:

```js
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+`",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        "workbench.action.createTerminalEditor",
        "workbench.action.moveEditorToNewWindow"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: seems to be a less-context-aware version of my 1.85 answer? and it's easier in 1.86.

Comment: @starball, which of yours do you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

It seems VS Code allows you to detach the terminal window, but it then will not show the output from the editor of the window you detached it from.

I have spent a while searching, and there is really no workaround other than to just run whatever file you are trying to debug from a separate terminal from the same CWD.  This also means you will need to save the file in the window you are editing the file in every time you want to run it.  huge pain.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Shift + P  input
'**create new Terminal in editor area**'
or
'**create new Terminal in editor area to the side**'

Answer (score 0):

I open a new terminal outside of vs-code and navigate to the dir.

I'm using React so I can open 2 terminals (outside of vs-code.)

I navigate to project dir then, npm start my project in the 1st terminal

then,

navigate to the same project dir then, run my git commands in the 2nd terminal.

By doing this I don't have to open any terminals in vs-code. Try it you might like it.

Answer (score 0):

**2023 Solution :**

1. `F1` to showCommands
2. Choose `Duplicate Workspace in New Window`
3. In the new window : `Create Terminal in Editor Area`

Answer (score 0):

I fear I'm missing the point, but I went to `File > New Window` and then dragged my `zsh` tab from the bottom pane to the new window and it all just worked.

[zsh tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOxxT.png)

Comment: yes, you can do this in more recent versions of VS Code (1.84/1.85+). see my answer for a keyboard shortcut that sort of automates it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using PowerShell inside the VSCode terminal, why don't you use the PowerShell console from the start menu. It's basically equivalent to using the terminal in separate windows. Hope it helps.[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbXfB.png)