# In VS Code, how do I bring the terminal up to the code editor section (without resizing the terminal)? "Terminal editors"

Tags: visual-studio-code

After getting more comfortable with `awslogs`, I am wondering if there's a way to actually open up or bring a terminal to the code editor view. For example, here's what I see in my iTerm2 app:

[image]

I don't really use iterm2 too much if I have to do some editing of files, but having this inside of VS Code in a tab would be really nice. Just would allow me to make changes to the Dockerfile and monitor the progress of the build from AWS.

Here's where I would like it to go:

[image]

I understand that this isn't really a "terminal" spot per se since it's typically at the bottom, but I was just curious to see if there was a way to do it without affecting the terminal on the bottom. In some rare cases it would be nice to attach to a tmux session from the code editor window so I can flip between that and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Insiders build now, and so presumably will be in v1.58, is the ability to put a terminal into an editor like you ask.  You can also **drag** a terminal into the editor area to crop it there!

There are these commands:

`Terminal: MoveTerminal into Editor Group`
`Terminal: Create Terminal Editor`
`workbench.action.terminal.moveToEditorInstance`

[image: terminal editors demo]

Comment: Ahh ok. I actually don't have that ability but I'm using version 1.57. When I go to the command palette, I don't have a `Terminal: MoveTerminal` available in the dropdown.

Comment: No, not until v1.58 - early July.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/68273093/836330