# Visual Studio Code Shortcut for Windows to open a specific terminal profile in one click

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have Visual Studio Code for Windows and I was wondering if there is a way to make a shortcut to open git bash in VS Code in one click?

I tried looking through the setting but didn't seem to find anything useful.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want something that automates opening the terminal panel, selecting the Git Bash Profile, and creating a terminal with that profile into one single action?

Comment: Did you mean Git Bash or Command line to apply git commands? Git Bash is an application. Why would you want a shortcut of that in VS code?

Comment: create a terminal profile for Git Bash and click the `+` icon  in the terminal, or execute the command **Create Terminal with Profile**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about a single *click*, but with keyboard shortcuts, you can do this:

```json
{
    "key": "", // TODO: pick something
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile",
    "args": {
        "profileName": "bash"
    }
}
```

Put that in your keybindings.json (use the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). This requires that you have already opened VS Code. If you're looking for something like a dock shortcut, then that's a different thing (that I don't know how to do).

Side note: If you actually want to open the VS Code integrated terminal in its own window, see [this answer post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76214341/11107541).