# VSCode layout with multiple splits per screen possible?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I use FancyZones to stretch VSCode over two monitors, which works well. But I was attempting to create a layout like the below and ran into two problems:

1. it seems I can either detach a single terminal window and have it a flexible editor tab, but it will not bring the other tabs from that view with it, and no longer be the 'target' for ctrl-` or move the entire terminal/debug/output 'view' thingy to the right, but then it can't be split any further, and always takes up the entire right side panel.
2. when I do move the view to the right, I can no longer to vertical splits like in the picture, instead splits always go horizontal, which I do not find very useful.

This is what I had in mind:

[image]

Coloured text corresponds to the same coloured frames.

If there are extensions that could help, I would also like to hear about those.

Comment: related and possible duplicates(?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/43362133/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43362133/11107541. see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10121

Comment: Thank you for your comment (did you mean to link that SO post twice ?), neither of those issues applies to my question; as I said, I use FancyZones for the multi-monitor aspect, and that is working fine. It's the layout within VSCode that I am concerned with

Comment: whoops. second one I meant to link to was https://stackoverflow.com/q/59665958/11107541. okay. looks like I misunderstood the question. sorry about that. I do think this question can probably be rephrased- especially the title to prevent more misunderstandings about what you're really asking about. It would help out if you spell out specific questions corresponding to the problems you have pointed out. Also note that it's generally recommended to avoid asking multiple questions in one question post unless they are very closely related.

Comment: You're right, the multi-monitor-aspect is really only relevant to explain the context behind the question, but doesn't really influence the actual question. Edited.