# VSCode - How do I split a file view to a separate window?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I drag a split tab over to a separate window, it opens a *separate instance* of the file. Any changes in this new instance only show in the other instance upon saving the file.

I want to open the *same instance* of a file to a separate window. where my edits in one view will show up in the other view instantly. The same behavior I get when splitting the view in a window.

Comment: Amusingly, using the Live Share extension and starting a live share session with myself works for this. Maybe there's a more suitable extension.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code open tab in new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362133/visual-studio-code-open-tab-in-new-window)

Comment: I don't see anything in there that addresses this. Or I guess it does answer the question, by confirming that's it's not possible. Since it links to a github issue that has been open for 7 years.

Comment: I think the accepted answer in that question is good enough to satisfy most users, and also confirms there is no real answer after all these years.

Comment: For this question, while it's not in the title, the body of the text is very specific about the fact that it needs to be the same instance, so the other question's accepted answer definitely does not apply. The second answer is more applicable, however, since that is the one that confirms that it's not possible.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77567725/6338809), the recent insiders has floating editor windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible since October 2023! https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_floating-editor-windows

Comment: please don't answer duplicate questions. flag them to be closed as duplicates. this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43362133/visual-studio-code-open-tab-in-new-window-on-another-screen-floating

Comment: Nice! It requires running a beta version of VS code (totally separate program. need to manually bring over your extensions and settings), but the fact that it's finally possible is excellent.

Answer (score 6):

I would also love to see a **Split to New Window** feature. A workaround while we wait is as follows:

- Open the source file you want to move
- Open a new Window via File -> New Window
- Grab the file by its name tab and drag it into the new window.
- Close the file in the original window

Answer (score -3):

These are the steps:

1. Open the file you are interested in splitting.
2. Find the icon to the left of the three dots on the top right corner:

[image]

When you hover it it says 'Split editor Right'.

3. Click on it and it will open a copy to the right where you will be able to type and see on real time the modifications on the file to the left.

Ready to go!

Comment: separate window. not a second pane in the same window

Comment: No idea then. If you struggle for space, just do what I wrote and then View > Appearance > Zen mode.