# Is there a way to open multiple Windows for the same Working directory. VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a situation thats not a major issue but I feel is possible.  Coming from a Video editing background, theres the need to work on multiple Monitors for various parts of your workflow.

I dont know if anyone is familiar with after effects or / Premier Pro where you can Drag your different pannels onto a new screen.

[Example of what Im trying to Describe in Adobe Premiere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhCsd.jpg)

Basically Instead of "open to the side" opening in the same window -> can this possibly be opened on a new screen so they are both save-able and editable to the same working directory.

Comment: You can split the view and then choose same file for both windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode - How do I split a file view to a separate window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62537626/vscode-how-do-i-split-a-file-view-to-a-separate-window)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can press `Ctrl`/`Cmd` + `Shift` + `P` to bring up the command palette and search for `Workspaces: Duplicate Workspace In New Window`

Comment: This is currently what I do, however the Feel im looking for is what's missing.. think of it like if you could just make the single workspace / editor double the screensize -> and had the window spill into both screens.

The thing thats missing is sharing the workspace enviornment at the same time. I dont want a whole second set of all my extensions / or a second terminal or a second set of anything just if that split window could be broken out of the original app... and dragged freely away from the main window

Comment: i guess the simplest way to sum it up is kind of like i said above... if you were to drag the tab as if you were positioning somewhere else in the vs code window layout. but when you drag out of the panel, a new window is opened, but it's just that single item ...   (like if you wanted your vscode terminal to be on a seperate screen at all times .. not the only way to see it is to force it to clog your whole app window

Comment: So sad that duplicating workspace in new window consuming RAM each window (2x RAM in total if have 2 Windows)

Comment: Upvoted. But, this doesn't actually open a new window into the *same* workspace. Rather, it duplicates all aspects of the workspace, then opens up a new window into this *new*, alternative workspace that just happens to look like the first workspace. So, workspace settings and changes are *not* actively shared between the two windows once you duplicate the workspace and open the second window. I can tell, because the name of the workspace in the 2nd window is `UNTITLED (WORKSPACE)`.

Answer (score 1):

The current VS Code Insiders has support for floating editor windows, see
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_floating-editor-windows.

The command is: `View: Move Active Editor into a New Window`