# How to get a workbench new editor window

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my home setting I get the option to "move into new window" a copy of my code editor, not a new instance of VS Code. But on my work PC, I can't find this option.

This is where I find this option on my home setup:

[image]

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

How can I activate this option on my Windows work PC?

**UP DATE:**

this is the config of the work PC wherre I dont have the optioon of  edit in a new window:
[image]

And this one is on the  home pc where I have the option of second new editor window
[image]

Comment: have you tried **File** > **New Window**

Comment: it give me a complete independant instance of vs code. What I search is only an editor window liked to the original instance of vs code

Comment: do you use the same version of VSC? What is the commandID of `Move into New Window`? is it defined in an extension

Comment: how can I get this information if it is define in extension?

Comment: first get the commandID via the keybind GUI

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Add this info for both your machines and clearly label which version info is for which machine.

Comment: @starball
 I ad the infos in the update section of my post.

Comment: I closed as a duplicate. read https://stackoverflow.com/a/77232931/11107541 in the linked Q&A. also, read my above comment carefully. also, please use the copy button in the `Help: About` to paste text instead of a [screenshot of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541).