# Is there any way to open vscode's debug console as an external window?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am developing a project flutter project in vscode and I like it that it automatically reloads the app on save, but I like to have my console on a different monitor so that I can always see the logs without needing to open up the integrated console.

I have tried to just run the project on an external console with the "flutter run" command. While this works I lose the auto reload on save. I know that Android Studio and the other JetBrains IDEs have this feature, but was not able to do so in vscode. While I can just use android studio I would rather not.

I have found this workaround, but it is also loses the reload on save.
[image]

Comment: see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77232931/11107541. the answer is no (at the time of this writing). only terminals and output panel support moving to new window right now. but see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/19793 (about debug view instead of console). If you want such a feature, [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md). If you do, please ping me here with a link to your issue ticket.