# How do I have more than one project open at a time in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are some times that I open up a new project that my other project closes.

Can I have two projects or two folders open at the same time?

Comment: There was another answer to this but I can't find it. Has it been deleted? Please undelete!

Answer (score 1):

You have to open two instances of visual studio code.

Comment: How to open two instances?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964825/how-does-one-open-multiple-instances-of-visual-studio-code